# Checking if all entries in the matrix are zero in Eigen Library

Tags: c++, eigen3

First of all, I'm not really sure if this is possible. I would like to check whether a matrix is zero or not in Eigen Library (note: I have to declare it). My solution is to check if all elements are zero. My question is Is there another way fulfill this task while keeping the size of the matrix unchanged?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

// true if it is empty, false if not
bool isEmpty(Eigen::MatrixXd& Z)
{
   bool check = true;

   for (int row(0); row < Z.rows(); ++row)
    for (int col(0); col < Z.cols(); ++col){
        if ( Z(row,col) != 0 ){
            check = false;
            break;
        }
     }

   return check;
}


int main()
{
    Eigen::MatrixXd Z(3,3);

    if ( isEmpty(Z) )
        std::cout << Z.size() << std::endl;
    else
        Z.setZero(0,0); // resize the matrix (not clever way I know)

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: An empty matrix is a matrix with 0 cols or 0 rows, isn't it?

Comment: Why the downvote? This is really getting weird with some mentalities. I have a problem and I've shown my effort and my way to solve it. What do really those ppl want?

Comment: @Kknd, it depends on which language you use.

Comment: is empty and is filled with Zeros are not the same. Probably explains the down votes. "is empty" usually means it is nullptr

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can set all coefficients to zeros without changing the matrix size with:

```
Z.setZero();
```

You can check that all coefficients are zero with:

```
bool is_empty = Z.isZero(0);
```

Here the argument is the relative precision to check that a number is a numerical zero. See [this doc](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a6dc0eb069536157ead1d46c660b9622d).

Comment: Link to exact method isZero - http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#title53